# Format content control on specific page

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

Could please someone help with MS Word's ContentControl formatting programmatically. 
I wrote a code that goes to specific ContentControl according to its tag. And this code works well by going to each ContentControl that is  specified by its Tag. However I need only to format only ContentControls on the page number 2.

I tried to limit the loop only for the specific bookmark, page, table, but it does not work. I don't need to go through each ContentContorl in the document, it takes too much time, which is opposite of the purpose of the macros. I am creating this macros to speed up report formatting.

Here is my code:

```
    Sub EditCCbyTag()

    Dim cc As ContentControl
    Dim strText As String

    Dim oThisdoc As Word.Document
    Dim oCC1 As ContentControl
    Dim oCCs1 As ContentControls
    Dim oCC2 As ContentControl
    Dim oCCs2 As ContentControls
    Dim oCC3 As ContentControl
    Dim oCCs3 As ContentControls

    Set oThisdoc = ActiveDocument
    Set oCCs1 = oThisdoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("DgDocDate01")

    For Each oCC1 In oCCs1
        If oCCs1.Count > 0 Then
        oCC1.Range.Select
        Dialogs(wdDialogContentControlProperties).Show

            strText = InputBox("Please enter the DATE of report")

            Set cc = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("DgDocDate01")(1)
            cc.Range.Text = strText
        End If

     Next oCC1

    ' the next CC DgDnvReportNo01

    Set oThisdoc = ActiveDocument
    Set oCCs2 = oThisdoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("DgDnvReportNo01")

    For Each oCC2 In oCCs2

        If oCCs2.Count > 0 Then

        oCC2.Range.Select
        Dialogs(wdDialogContentControlProperties).Show

            strText = InputBox("Please enter the NUMBER of report")

            Set cc = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("DgDnvReportNo01")(1)
            cc.Range.Text = strText
        End If
    Next oCC2

    ' the next CC DgRevNo01

    Set oThisdoc = ActiveDocument
    Set oCCs3 = oThisdoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("DgRevNo01")

    For Each oCC3 In oCCs3

        If oCCs3.Count > 0 Then

        oCC3.Range.Select
        Dialogs(wdDialogContentControlProperties).Show

            strText = InputBox("Please enter the REVISION of report")

            Set cc = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("DgRevNo01")(1)
            cc.Range.Text = strText

        End If

    Next oCC3

    MsgBox "Done!"

    End Sub
```

Comment: " tried to limit the loop only for the specific bookmark, page, table, but it does not work" How does it not work? That would certainly be the most efficient method and I am quite sure it CAN work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to format content controls on page 2, you should check the `Information` property of the content control's `Range`, e.g.:

```
Dim cc as ContentControl
If cc.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) = 2 Then
    ... Do work ...
End If
```

The `wdActiveEndPageNumber` constant refers to the physical page. If you desire the logical page (e.g. if Word has been instructed to restart page numbering) instead, you should use the `wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber` constant. See [this link](http://word.tips.net/T000728_Determining_the_Current_Page_Number.html) for source and details.

Comment: Thank you DanL for you response! But I cannot figure out, sorry. I tried to incorporate it to the code, but VBA gives me an error message stating that object variable is not defined or WIth block variable is not defined. Could you please expand the code? The content controls that I want to edit are only in the page nummer 1  and in the table. I tried to set table as range, and all other stuff, but still cannot figure it out.

Comment: You should include the code that you use to set the table in your question. Then, you should specify what line your code fails on. The error is incredibly unspecific - it merely states that you didn't define something.

Comment: Hi DanL, it was solved. First the table is selected, then the selection page via selection.information is identified, and after that if then statement is run. It worked out. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Opensoul Good to hear. Please mark as answer if it solved your problem :-)